# C++ debugger "gdb.exe --version" error in Eclipse Mars+MinGW

Tags: c++, eclipse, gdb, mingw

When debugging a C++ project in Eclipse I get the following error:

> 'Launching Project.exe' has encountered a problem.
>
> Could not determine GDB version using command:
>
> D:\Programme\MinGW\bin\gdb.exe --version

Some Posts on Stackoverflow suggested linking MinGW\bin\gdb.exe directly in the C++/GDB settings solves the problem, but as you can see it didn't for me.
Any suggestions?

Edit: Tried `mingw-get.exe install gdb` in MinGW\bin, got an error that said the latest version is already installed.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for my --version error:
When I ran $ gdb --version from the MinGW shell I got an error message saying zlib1.dll was not found.
I copied zlib1.dll from the \Debug folder of my C++ project into MinGW\bin and now it's working.

Answer (score 0):

If gdb --version works in cmd, then try change path in eclipse - run - debug configurations - debugger - GDB debugger to C:\MinGW\gdb64\bin\gdb.exe, the default one in C:\MinGW\bin could be 32-bit.